# React draft-js color picker lost inline style

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am using Draftjs Editor to generate html content. Also using a package draft-js-color-picker that generates inline styles on the Editor content and I am able to extract that to html and save it on the DB. But when I get that same html and convert to the Editor content format it lost all the inline css. How do I render the style inline inside Draftjs Editor?

```
import { AtomicBlockUtils, Editor, EditorState, RichUtils, convertFromHTML, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
import ColorPicker, { colorPickerPlugin } from 'draft-js-color-picker';
import { stateToHTML } from 'draft-js-export-html';
(...)

class CreateComment extends Component {
 (...)

 render() {
   return(<Editor
     blockRendererFn={mediaBlockRenderer}
     customStyleFn={this.picker.customStyleFn}
     blockStyleFn={this.getBlockStyle}
     customStyleMap={styleMap}
     editorState={editorState}
     handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     onTab={this.onTab}
     ref="editor"
     spellCheck={true}
   />)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you finally manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

although it is an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/2118) in their Github repo, I found a solution that uses `draft-js-import-html` library ([link](https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/tree/master/packages/draft-js-import-html))

```
import { stateFromHTML } from 'draft-js-import-html';

// list of your custom styles
const styleMap: any = {
  'ORANGE': {
    color: 'rgb(242, 113, 28)'
  },
  'DARKYELLOW': {
    color: 'rgb(226, 180, 1)'
  },
  'BLACK': {
    color: 'rgb(27, 28, 29)'
  }
}
const importHtmlOptions = {
  customInlineFn: (element, { Style }) => {
    if (element.tagName === 'SPAN') {
        const color = element.style.color // the element color in RGB

        const customStyle = Object.keys(colorStyleMap).find((styleKey: string) => colorStyleMap[styleKey].color === color)
        if (customStyle) {
            return Style(customStyle)
        }
    }
  }
const content = stateFromHTML(yourHtmlContent, importHtmlOptions);
const newEditState = EditorState.createWithContent(content)
setNewEditorState(newEditState)
```